# Checkbox value not getting in controller even it's checked asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am developing application in ASP.Net MVC and getting wrong value of checkbox in controller. I am using following code for showing checkbox in view:

```
@Html.CheckBox("ENABLED", new { @class = "checkSwitch", @checked = "checked" })
```

It's related property in model class is this

```
public Nullable<bool> ENABLED { get; set; }
```

I am using jquery plugin at here http://labs.lukepeters.me/iphone-checkbox-switch/ which display this checkbox like this:

[image]

html code generated for it when it's checked(Yes) is like this:

[image]

html code generated for it when it's unchecked(No) is like this:

[image]

Now issue is that when I open form with this checkbox initially checkbox displays properly and when I make chekcbox checked/unchecked only once then all works fine. Means if checkbox is checked initially and I make it unchecked, save data then it return unchecked(false) which is right. But suppose checkbox is checked initially and I make it unchecked, again I make is checked, save data this time instead checkbox is checked, it return unchecked(false). Also suppose checkbox is unchecked initially and I make it checked, again I make is unchecked, save data this time checkbox is unchecked(false).
It really weird don't know what is problem.

Any help is really helpful. Thanks.....

Comment: This is not related to `css`

Comment: In both instances there is a Value of the checkbox set to "true".

Is this being set by the switch javascript?

Comment: see what value is being sent in the POST

Comment: Thanks for reply all. @matt-dot-net I saw posted values in Request object in controller, suppose initially checkbox is unchecked and I checked it then value posted is ENABLED=true&ENABLED=false also my viewmodel get binded properly for ENABLED only for first change it's right. Here first value is for checkbox and second value is for hidden field. But suppose initially checkbox is unchecked and I checked it, again unchecked and checked it, even checkbox for ENABLED is checked it posts ENABLED=false. I am really frustrated and no idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Model with strongly typed View, try change your Razor to:

```
@model YourModel
<!-- [...] Html Content [...] -->
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ENABLED, new { @class = "checkSwitch", @checked = "checked" })
```

Then, inside your controller, the action should be something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostMethod(YourModel model)
{
    var isChecked = model.ENABLED;
    // [...]
}
```

Or, you may try another approach as:

```
public ActionResult PostMethod(bool ENABLED) { /*[...]*/ }
```